# Why is search functionality not working on this page?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, proxy, firebug

we deliver micro-site content for our client. Our content is injected into a wrapper that is supplied by another developer.

To deliver our content we host the wrapper as well as the content. The user can access this at

http://fundcentre.[redacted].ie/ (try a search for '[redacted]')

For the other content that is not ours, the other developer hosts a similar (though slightly different) wrapper and delivers the content. the user accesses this here:

http://www.[redacted].ie/ (try a search for '[redacted]')

The wrapper contains a search box, which does not work for us but it works for the other developer. I took a look at the network traffic with FireBug but it appears that when I do the search from the wrapper that we're hosting, I'm getting a "407 Proxy Access Denied" error. My guess is their proxy has a problem with the fact that the search is being conducted from a page hosted outside the scope of their proxy.

It was also suggested that there were javascript errors on the page that were preventing the search from executing but I can't see any. Also, I don't think I'd get as far as the proxy error if that was the case.

I don't really understand this stuff too well though, so could somebody with a bit more experience please take a look and maybe shed some light on this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the search box and the button next to it (the magnifying glass) are both causing the whole page form to submit *after* they try to set the page URL to the search URL.  When you type into the search field and hit "Enter", the outer form that's wrapped around the entire page is submitted. When the magnifying glass is clicked, it *tries* to load the search results but because it's an image button the click *also* causes the outer form to be submitted.

I'm not exactly sure how best to fix it, partly because I think the entire page design should be thrown out.  But if you're stuck with it, it *might* be possible to get it working by ditching that in-line Javascript on the button (since it's not working anyway) and then wrapping the search stuff with its own `<form>` directed to the search page. Having a `<form>` within a `<form>` is bad mojo but that's hard to avoid in a design that puts the whole page in a `<form>` to start with.

Alternatively, you could try handling keypress events on the search input to detect "Enter", and have that handler and the code on the button both return "false" to stop the outer form submission.

*edit* — as to why that works on the other site, well it appears to me that there the outer form really is the "search" functionality somehow, as they don't have the click handler on the search button at all, so all it'll do is submit the outer form anyway.

*edit again* — also, I never see that "proxy" issue. The search from your page works fine for me if I first fix the inline Javascript on the button so that it ends with `; return false`.  That actually may be all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, your suggestion to 'return false' seems to be the solution. I agree with you about the design being thrown out. There were a lot of uninformed decisions made early in the design phase that I had no input on. It's a bit of a disgrace. However, for what it's worth it seems this problem lies with the other developer. Thanks for helping point this out.

Comment: I've been there too!  Good luck etc.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem that your  tags' action are pointing to different scripts. One is pointing to "Home.aspx" and the other to "/Default.aspx". 
The two links are in different subdomains, so maybe you would like to change the action of the subdomain so it contains the full location of the action (ex. "http://www.newireland.ie/Default.aspx")

Comment: The search itself however is actually a different URL from *either* of those two.